# Trying to send form elements, only the submit button is showing up

Tags: php, html

I have a file `sign_up.php` that holds my website sign up form. The form's action is my `sitesignup.php` file which is supposed to take the information gathered by my form , make sure it's all valid and safe then send it off to my SQL database. The problem I am running into is that the form elements are not showing up in the $_POST array in `sitesignup.php`, only the submit button is.

Could someone please give me some insight into what I am doing wrong?

File: user_interface/sign_up.php

```
<head >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="user_interface_tables.css">
</head>
<table class="outer">
    <tr>
    <form name="sign_up" method="post" action="user_interface/sitesignup.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="pagereference" value="<?php echo  $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" >
        <td>
        <table class="inner">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3"><strong>User Registration Form</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="150">First Name <font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td width="6">:</td>                
                <td width="290"><input type="text" id="first_name"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Last Name <font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td ><input type="text" id="last_name"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >User Name <font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td "><input type="text" id="user_name"></td>               
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Email<font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td ><input type="text" id="email"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Password<font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td ><input type="password" id="password1"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Confirm Password<font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td ><input type="password" id="password2"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td >Registration Code</td>
                <td >:</td>             
                <td ><input type="text" id="registration_code"></td>                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"name="submit" ></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
        </td>
    </form>
    </tr>
</table>
```

File: user_interface/sitesignup.php

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Output: array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }

Answer (score 0):

I realized the problem right as I was about to post. Just so other people can learn from my mistake, notice how I used id="blah", for my form elements.

the `name` tag is what is used in the the identify the form elements, the `id` tag is what I was using for CSS, I guess I just wasn't thinking when I wrote it...

For example:
instead of

```
<tr>
    <td >User Name <font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
    <td >:</td>             
    <td "><input type="text" id="user_name"></td>               
</tr>
```

I would write

```
<tr>
    <td >User Name <font id="asterisk">*</font></td>
    <td >:</td>             
    <td "><input type="text" name="user_name"></td>             
</tr>
```

now my var dump is showing up with all of my form elements :D

> array(7) { ["first_name"]=> string(3) "dan" ["last_name"]=> string(3)
>   "dan" ["user_name"]=> string(4) "name" ["email"]=> string(4) "name"
>   ["password1"]=> string(4) "name" ["password2"]=> string(4) "name"
>   ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }